# MySQL Remote Access

Tags: linux, mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

We have a **MySQL** database server which is running on a **Amazon Linux Instance** which we would like to connect to remotely.

We have set the access for  the port **3306** for our LAN gate way IP  in the [AWS security group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html).

We have executed the following command to grant access to our IP from where we will connect the database and the output as follows

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'our IP Address' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Still we are getting the following error message while trying to connect the database using MySQL administrator tool:

```
Host: Our IP address where MySQL server runs
User : root
Password: Our password
MySQL Error: Could not connect to the specified instance.
MySQL error number 2003
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'MySQL server IP Address'(10060)
```

How could we solved this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Sometime, 'flush privileges;' help a lot, after adding your user... (depends on the version of MySQL). Otherwise, i'd say you forgot the security group modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to identify the source of your problem.

- **First**: check whether the problem comes from the network connexion. Try to ping the IP or the domain:

  ```
  $ ping $YOUR_IP
  ```
- **Second**: check your identifiers by a direct connexion. Your error may result in a misconfiguration:

  ```
  $ mysql -h $YOUR_IP -P 3306 -u root -p
  ```

  You should see a prompt.

If the two tests above succeed, you should check your application configuration file.

**Note:** It's not a good practice to use the *root* user for remote access, you should create a new user (specific to your need) with limited rights.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to make sure that the firewall (iptables) is not blocking access.

Answer (score 0):

Possible areas to check:

- **Firewalls:** Double check that port 3306 is open (at least to your IP address) in both your EC2 security group and your servers firewall (iptables, ufw etc).
- **MySQL Config:** Check that MySQL server is configured (`my.cnf`) to listen on a TCP port, as opposed to a UNIX socket. E.g.

```
    [mysqld]
    port = 3306
    bind-address = 0.0.0.0
    #skip-networking
```